# Is there a way to get all configured routes in WebFlux without actuator?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-actuator

I wonder if there's a way to get all configured mappings in runtime without using Actuator's [MappingsEndpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/web/mappings/MappingsEndpoint.html).

With MappingsEndpoint it's as easy as pie (in Kotlin notation, in Java it's basically the same):

```
       @Autowired val mappingsEndpoint: org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.mappings.MappingsEndpoint
       mappingsEndpoint.mappings().contexts.values
           .asSequence()
           .mapNotNull { it.mappings["dispatcherHandlers"] }
           .filterIsInstance<Map<*, *>>()
           .mapNotNull { it["webHandler"] as? List<*> }
           .flatten()
           ...
```

However it makes use of Actuator and not all setups permit the MappingsEndpoint bean.

I wonder if it's possible to somehow query configured routes for the whole server from within Java/Kotlin code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use RequestMappingHandlerMapping get to a full list of the registered mappings.

```
@Autowired private RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

...

Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethods = handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods();

List<String> mappings = handlerMethods.keySet().stream().map((handlerMethod -> handlerMethod.getMethodsCondition() + ":" + handlerMethod.getPathPatternsCondition())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will give you a list of Strings that look like,

```
[PUT]:[/endpoint]
[GET]:[/endpoint]
```

etc